Should you say a beracha when you see a gentile child prodigy
The Talmud in tractate Berachot 58a mentions a beracha that should be recited when you see a gentile scholar. Many poskim hold it is required for the scholar mentioned in the Gemara to observe the Noahide laws in order to recite the blessing. If there is a gentile child prodigy, and they also observe the 7 noahide laws, should the beracha be recited on them? Or no, as the Mishnah in Pirkei Avot says wisdom comes at age 40, which might not be true for everyone but is a general idea about age correlating with wisdom.

Why ask about gentile scholars and not Torah scholars, also from that same gemara?

Torah scholars are evaluated on the basis of their Torah learning, which starts before 40. It could be a gentile scholar is evaluated mainly by their wisdom @DoubleAA

I would guess it applies at whatever age the scholar gets to the level to be worthy of reciting the blessing.
